# Why does nil check fail

Tags: redis, lua

I am using Lua to query redis and want to check if a key isn't present but am confused as to why my code isn't working:

```
local bulk = redis.call("HMGET", KEYS[1], "p1", "p2")
for i, v in ipairs(bulk) do
    if (i == 1) then
        if (v == nil) then
            return nil  -- This is never entered
        end
    end
end
```

however the following code does work:

```
local bulk = redis.call("HMGET", KEYS[1], "p1", "p2")
for i, v in ipairs(bulk) do
    if (i == 1) then
        v = v or 0
        if (v == 0) then
            return nil  -- This does work
        end
    end
end
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `ipairs` to iterate over your table. The iteration will end at the first element that is `nil`. Hence `v` can never equal nil inside your for loop.
So you'll never enter the `if (v== nil)` statement.

[From the Lua Reference Manual 6.1 Basic Functions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.1):

> ipairs (t) Returns three values (an iterator function, the table t,
>   and 0) so that the construction
>
> ```
>  for i,v in ipairs(t) do body end
> ```
>
> will iterate over the key–value pairs (1,t[1]), (2,t[2]), ..., up to the first nil value.

Actually you cannot use any of the standard iterators to find nil values.

If you only want to check if `bulk[1]` is `nil`:

Replace

```
local bulk = redis.call("HMGET", KEYS[1], "p1", "p2")
for i, v in ipairs(bulk) do
    if (i == 1) then
        if (v == nil) then
            return nil  -- This is never entered
        end
    end
end
```

with

```
local bulk = redis.call("HMGET", KEYS[1], "p1", "p2")
if not bulk[1] then return end
```

`return` and `return nil` are the same btw.

In case `bulk[1]` may be validly `false` check vs `nil` explicitly.

```
if bulk[1] == nil then return end
```

This code:

```
local bulk = redis.call("HMGET", KEYS[1], "p1", "p2")
for i, v in ipairs(bulk) do
    if (i == 1) then
        v = v or 0
        if (v == 0) then
            return nil  -- This does work
        end
    end
end
```

works because `bulk[1]` is either `0` or `false` in which case you replace it with `0`.

A quick resarch confirms that you get false values instead of nil from the Redis Lua bindings. So using `ipairs` should be fine. You should just check if the value equals `false`, not `nil`.

Comment: @James next time, just `print(bulk[1])` and you instantly know that it is `false`